# Temperature dependent output voltage change

Tags: operational-amplifier

I set up and ran the circuit below with a TL084 and I get a nice 25kHz sinusoidal oscillation without any problems. I collect the sine signal in a capacitor through the peak detector I made with the other  TL084. When the ambient temperature changes, the amplitude of the sine signal increases and therefore the output of the peak detector increases above the level I want to observe. In such a case, I have already observed that the + and - saturation values of TL084 change depending on the temperature. I think that the LC tank circuit is exposed to more bias current due to the increase in the opamp output and as a result, its amplitude increases.

Since I cannot achieve constant current driving in such a circuit, can the amplitude be kept constant? How can I compensate for this type of problem? I researched thermistors but it was not possible to adapt them to this circuit and they are also non-linear. At a temperature increase of approximately 25 degrees, there is a 50mV change in the sine amplitude and it occurs almost linearly.

[image: lc oscillator]

Comment: BJTs have a commonly understood change in their BE junction of about -2 mV/K. Given the 25 C change and the 50 mV effect, this would be about in the right ballpark. Might start by looking around for BJTs here.

Comment: Make a feedback control with precise compensated voltage reference like tl431.

Answer (score 1):

> *can the amplitude be kept constant? How can I compensate for this type
> of problem?*

If you derive the formulas for the op-amp circuit in your question, there is nothing that "limits" the amplitude of the oscillation hence, for it to be amplitude-stable, there has to be a non-linearity somewhere that can stabilize things. That comes with a price; imperfect sinewave quality but, it can be managed.

Usually, in simple op-amp circuits (like in the question), the amplitude will increase until the output stages begin to saturate and you get an ugly rounding-off of the top and bottom sections of the output waveform. Or, op-amp slew rate limiting kicks-in and you find that the slopes of the sinewave are linear rather than sinusoidal.

The options that I see that are open to you are: -

- Amplitude control using a JFET (quite often seen in Wien bridge oscillators)
- Amplitude control using a non-linear resistor in the negative feedback (again, Wien bridge oscillators quite often use a small lamp that as it warms it increases resistance)
- Diode shaping circuits in the feedback that reduce rate of change of gain as amplitude rises
- Precision clipping/limiting circuits inserted half way along R4 (in your circuit)